# NodeJs Browser-Sync + Concat не объединяет ИЗМЕНЯЕМЫЙ файл, как отследить ошибку?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть Browser-Sync, он ищет файл, который я изменил и он с другими js файлами объединяет в один файл 'scripts.min.js'. У меня есть свой хостинг.
Проблема в том, что при первом запуске sudo gulp все файлы объединяются в один и все нормально работают, но если я изменяю файл common.js то concat объединяет все файлы, КРОМЕ COMMON.js ,думаю из-за того, что в этом файле ошибка, но я ее никак не могу отследить или не в этом дело.Так вот не подскажите, что делать?

gulpfile.js (сократил)

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'app/libs/slick-1.8.0/slick/slick.min.js',
    'app/libs/jQuery.mmenu/dist/jquery.mmenu.all.js',
    'app/js/common.js', // Always at the end
    ])
  .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js').on("error", notify.onError()))
  //.pipe(uglify()) // Mifify js (opt.)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
  //.pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browsersync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
    notify: true,
    open:false,
    //host:"192.168.56.1",
  })
});
gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browsersync.reload)
});
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что через FTP слишком большая задержка и файл брался, но он был пустым.
Решение:

```
+ var sleep = require('sleep'),

gulp.task('js', function() {
    sleep.msleep(1500);
    return gulp.src([
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'app/libs/jQuery.mmenu/dist/hammer/hammer.js',
        'app/libs/jQuery.mmenu/dist/jquery.mmenu.all.js',
        'app/libs/slick-1.8.0/slick/slick.min.js',
        'app/js/common.js', // Always at the end
        ])
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js')) 
    //.pipe(uglify()) // Mifify js (opt.)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));

    //.pipe(browserSync.stream())
});
```